# Python: class inheritance

Tags: python, class

For an assignement for school I need to make a chess game in python. But I'm stuck at a little obstacle.

I want the user to make a chess-piece like this:

```
p=Pawn(White)
```

And I want a print to work like this:

```
print(p)  ##Output: White pawn
```

And in order to get this done I need to use class inheritance, but it doesn't work for me. Here is what I have currently:

```
WHITE=1
BLACK=2

class ChessPiece:

     def __init__(self,color):
         self.color=color

     def __str__(self):
         if self.color==1:
             print('Witte',self.name)
         else:
             print("Zwart ",self.name)

class Pawn(ChessPiece):
    def __init__(self):
         self.naam='pawn'
         self.kleur=kleur
```

Comment: Is the name `self.naam` or `self.name`. You must choose and use the same everywhere.

Comment: Shouldn't the variables be called the same? I mean, `name` and `color` on both classes, not `naam` and `kleur`.

Comment: As a sidenote, a common trick with inheritance is to use `self.__class__.__name__`. That gives you the name of the class, here that would be `Pawn`.

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* isn't a useful problem description; give a [mcve].

Comment: Since you have only two colours in chess, a somewhat better choice than `1,2` would be `0,1` or `True,False`.

Answer (score 1):

This is modified version of your code:

```
WHITE=1
BLACK=2

class ChessPiece:

     def __init__(self,color):
         self.color=color

     def __str__(self):
         if self.color==1:
             return "White {}".format(self.__class__.__name__)
         else:
             return "Black {}".format(self.__class__.__name__)

class Pawn(ChessPiece):
    def __init__(self, color):
         ChessPiece.__init__(self,color)
         self.naam = 'pawn'
         self.kleur = 'kleur'


p = Pawn(WHITE)
print(p)
```

Some points was neglected in your code that is `__str__` should return a string and not to print it and you should call base class `__init__` in successor